# What type of lookup can i use for a foreign key field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, lookup

I have a search form in my application. I am performing some request with it within the database of my application.

The category field is a foreign key relationship in my application. When trying to make a search, i got this error because the category is a foeirgn key and perhaps i used the wrong lookup expression for this. What is the right way i can go about this please? Thanks

Error log

```
Exception Type: FieldError at /searchproduct/
Exception Value: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

models.py

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':      
        product_name =  request.GET.get('search')    
        products = Product.objects.filter(Q(category__name__icontains=product_name) | Q(country__name__icontains=product_name) | Q(name__icontains=product_name))
        context = {"products": products}
        return render(request, "core/search.html", context)
    else:
        result = "Sorry there is no product with that name"
        return render(request, "core/search.html", context)
```

Comment: What you are trying to query is the `name` of the `Category`, so you should use `category__name__icontains=product_name`.

Comment: Thanks so much, its solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use a lookup on one of the related fields (I believe `name` field of `category` here). Use `__` to traverse over relations in lookups. Also `queryset1 or queryset2` does not make much sense. Do you want to use OR in the query? Use [`Q` objects [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for that:

```
from django.db.models import Q

products = Product.objects.filter(Q(category__name__icontains=product_name) | Q(name__icontains=product_name))
```

Comment: Please Sir, if i wuld like to filter also with the country field whereby I am using the django-country package for it, how can i go about that.

Comment: @coderboy It is better to use forms when we have multiple fields on which we want to filter. See [Custom forms](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/#custom-forms) section of django-countries. Using that make a form and if the form is valid you can then get the values you need from `form.cleaned_data` with which you can filter.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using seluk comment above.

Since I was trying to query is the name of the Category, I simply used the query `category__name__icontains=product_name`

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':      
        product_name =  request.GET.get('search')    
        products = Product.objects.filter(category__name__icontains=product_name) or Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=product_name)
        context = {"products": products}
        return render(request, "core/search.html", context)
    else:
        result = "Sorry there is no product with that name"
        return render(request, "core/search.html", context)
```